# How to get IE or applets to revert back to using old version of installed JRE?

Tags: java

I installed JRE 6 on my existing 1.4.2 causing some applets in IE6 requiring 1.4.2 to stop working, how can i revert this back without uninstalling JRE6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you deploy your applet? I assume you are using a jnlp file descriptor (Java Web Start).
If so, maybe you find this link useful:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html

You can use this advice when deploying:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html

As far as I know, the standard in deploying applets nowadays is to use the deployJava script AND a jnlp file. This way you can detect the client's jre's using

> getJREs()

Choose the appropriate one and then initiate your applet by calling:

> runApplet(attributes, parameters, minimumVersion)

Please take in account that depending on the Java Plugin the client runs, above approach might not work. DeployJava gives you an option to handle that

> **To deploy an applet that runs on the old and new Java Plug-ins,
>   specify the applet tag attributes and JNLP parameters as shown in the
>   example below:**

```
var attributes = {codebase:'http://java.sun.com/products/plugin/1.5.0/demos/jfc/Java2D',
                      code:'java2d.Java2DemoApplet.class', archive:'Java2Demo.jar', width:710, height:540} ; 
var parameters = {fontSize:16, jnlp_href:'java2d.jnlp'} ; 
var version = '1.6' ; 
deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
```

Answer (score 0):

On windows, go into control panel, select the java icon, click on the java tab and then on the view button. This should show you a list of installed runtimes, enable and disable whichever you need.